# Run a thread inside an active object

Tags: multithreading, object, symbian

I have a class which is derived from CTimer class. I have an instance of RThread as data member to periodically invoke CTimer::After() method. The code is:

```
void CTimerThread::RunL()
{
    qDebug() << "Value=" << ++iCounter;

    if (iThread->ExitType() == EExitKill)
    {
        if (KErrNone == CreateThread())
            iThread->Resume();
    }
}

void CTimerThread::StartL()
{
    qDebug() << "In the StartL( );";
    if(isThreadCreated == EFalse)
        User::LeaveIfError(CreateThread ());

    iThread->Resume();
}

TInt CTimerThread::ThreadFunction(TAny *sender)
{
    CTrapCleanup* cleanupStack = CTrapCleanup::New();

    CTimerThread* host = (CTimerThread*)sender;

    forever {
         host->After(host->iInterval->Int());
         if (!host->isSchedulStarted)
                   {
                       CActiveScheduler::Start();
                       host->isSchedulStarted = ETrue;
                   }
     }
    delete cleanupStack;
    return 1;
}

TInt CTimerThread::CreateThread()
{
    TInt err = KErrNone;

    _LIT(KNameBase, "Thread_");
    TBuf<10> name(KNameBase);
    name.AppendNum(iCounter);

    err = iThread->Create(name, CTimerThread::ThreadFunction, 4096, NULL, this);

    if( err == KErrNone)
        isThreadCreated = ETrue;

    return err;
}
```

When I execute StartL() I always get **a data abort exception has occured**. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Active objects are inherently thread-specific since they rely on the thread semaphore for signaling (`User::WaitForRequest()`, `User::RequestComplete()` etc.). You cannot directly invoke active objects of another thread.

Another issue: your thread does not have an active scheduler installed. If you plan to use active objects in a newly created thread, `CActiveScheduler::Install()` an active scheduler first.

Comment: Hi @laalto I also used the active scheduler in the ThreadFunction(), but the panic raised again. Moreover, I run new thread in the CTimerThread which is active object. This is exactly like one of nokia examples[link]http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/db839245-80fb-4a77-8e9a-35d1568310c3/S60_Platform_Multiple_Threads_Example_v1_1.zip.html.

Comment: @user1027344 Still you cannot use active objects of another threads. Note that in the example you linked the CTimer active object is in the main application thread (where the app framework creates the active scheduler for you). The other threads themselves do not use any active objects.

Comment: Hi
The scenario which I have is like below:
There is a class like CMyClass that have an active object like C_AO_Class and a RThread as data members. I want to run the thread inside and periodically, invoke the C_AO_Class::Foo() method that it makes an asynchronous request. How can I do that? If I invoke another method of C_AO_Class which doesn't make an async request, it works fine.